# Android: Dealing HashMap.put for image

Tags: android, image, listview, simpleadapter

I want to add an image to the listview, how do i do so? The names and type are displaying properly. Currently stuck here.

```
.//other codes
.
.
try{
        JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(res);
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length();i++){                        
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            JSONObject e = arr.getJSONObject(i);

            map.put("placeID", ""+ e.getString("placeID"));
            map.put("placeName",""+ e.getString("placeName"));
            map.put("placeType", ""+ e.getString("placeType"));
            map.put("image", R.drawable.ball_green);

            mylist.add(map);            
        }       
    }catch(JSONException e)        {
         Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.places, 
                    new String[] { "placeName", "placeType" }, 
                    new int[] { R.id.placeName, R.id.placeType });
.
.
.//other codes
```

I want the image appropriately like:

[image: ListView]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `R.java` class is auto-generated at build-time and maintains a 'list' of integers which are resource ids. In other words `R.<anything>` is an `Integer` and doesn't directly represent the resource (string, drawable etc).

As your `HashMap` is expecting `String` types for both keys and values, you'll need to convert the `ball_green` resource id to a `String`. Example...

```
map.put("image", String.valueOf(R.drawable.ball_green));
```

In order to use it again you'll have to convert that `String` back to an `Integer` when using it to set the image of a widget such as an `ImageView` etc.

Comment: I would like to know, if I have downloaded a bitmap how can I use it in the the map.put("image", String.valueOf(bitmapfile));
Is there a way to connect the downloaded file here?

Comment: @Joe : If you are downloading a file (bitmap or any other type) it will never have an int value assigned to it in the R.java class so you wouldn't have to use `String.valueOf(...)`. The OP was using `HashMap<String, String>` - if you're doing the same then simply use the path to the downloaded file as the second string.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think adding image into a hashtable is a good idea. you can easily add a custom adapter, don't use SimpleAdapter.